# Calculate elevation of the sun in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, astronomy

There is a great PHP function called [date_sun_info()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sun-info.php) which takes time and location params and returns, among other things, the sunrise, sunset, and "transit" which is the time when the sun is at its highest at that location. Brilliant!

What I want to know is - given the date, sunrise, transit and sunset times is there any way to calculate the angle of elevation (altitude) of the sun throughout that day?

Comment: Unless there is a PHP function to do just that (have you checked the manual?!) you'll have better luck asking around in an astronomy forum. Once you get the formula - deriving the algorithm to compute the elevation should be trivial..

Comment: I don't think the date, sunrise, transit, and sunset times uniquely identify a latitude and longitude, but maybe it's possible to compute the angle of elevation at both locations.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few articles which might help you:

- [How to compute rise/set times and altitude above horizon](http://www.stjarnhimlen.se/comp/riset.html)
- [Calculate power gain of home solar system](http://www.weather-watch.com/smf/index.php?topic=54992.0)